# Count the length of all polylines from one shapefile within the segments of polygon of another shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, count, within

I have polylines with counted lengths. And i have the polygon shapefile (fishnet). I want to calculate the sum af lengh of polylines and amount of lines that are within the border of each segment of polygon (fishnet).

How do I can to do it using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1?

By "Counted lengths" I mean that I used "calculate geometry" to obtain lengths. I want to use fishnet to make a spline. For this I need to fill the column "sum", for example. But I do not want to use a ruler to measure the lengths of each line within the border of each cell of fishnet.

So I want to make it automatically using two shapefiles: stream orders (polylines) and fishnet (polygon).

Than I will put information to the point shapefile and make a spline. I did it before but I used ruler instead of ArcMap tools.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include more information, such as which GIS software and version are you using, what you have tried and what happens when you try it.  What do you mean by "counted lengths"?

Comment: ArcGis 10.1. "Counted lengths" means that I used "calculate geometry" to obtain lengths (sorry for my explanation). I want to use fishnet to  make a spline. For this I need to fill the column "sum", for example. But I do not want to use a ruler to measure the lengths of each line within the border of each cell of fishnet. So I want to make it automatically using two shapefiles: stream orders (polylines) and fishnet (polygon). Than I will put information to the point shapefile and make a spline. I did it before but I used ruler instead of ArcMap tools.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include any extra information.  Comments are for potential answerers to request clarification, your response should be as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Intersect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) your fishnet and streams, outputting lines. This will cut all of the streams at the fishnet boundaries and attribute the lines with the fishnet cell attributes it falls within.
2. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) the streams from #1, based on the fishnet ID. This will collapse all streams within each cell into a single feature. If you will need a count of the stream features within each fishnet grid cell, specify a 'COUNT' statistic in the Dissolve.
3. Calculate the length of the features from #2.
4. If you need to attach the total length of streams within each fishnet cell, join the result from #3 to the fishnet grid, on the fishnet ID, and field calculate the total length into the fishnet feature class.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it is do not solve my problem. I want to put the lengths of all streams within the cell of fishnet, where they are, into the attribute table of this fishnet. For example: I have cell of fishnet #1; there are few streams within this cell; as a result I want to calculate a sum of lengths of streams and put it into the attribute table of fishnet for this cell. Second type of data is amount of lines that are within the cell, which I want to put in another column of fishnet's attribute table.

Comment: See edited point #4 above, where you join the dissolved streams back into the fishnet to store the total length within each fishnet grid cell. Also, edited #2 for the count.

Comment: Yeh, I have got it already. Thak you very much. Can you make an advice, how to make a spline using not the length of lines but by anount of lines of each cell? For example, I have 2 lines in one cell and 6 lines in another. Two obtain lines I use Split Line at Verticles.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spline"? You might need to edit your original question with a picture. I think of spline in GIS as a type of interpolation, like: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/spline.htm

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to do similar thing in the future:

You can perform a Spatial Join to reducte the number of steps needed for this piece of work.

Spatial Join (Analysis) >> Target Feature = fishnet grid >> Join Features = Polylines >> INTERSECT.